# Geoposicionar el más cercano en android

Tags: android, google-maps

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en la que cojo la posición actual del dispositivo y tengo un listado de cajeros automáticos con sus correspondientes coordenadas. Lo que estoy intentando hacer es saber si existe un algoritmo en la api de google maps de Android para calcular cual sería el cajero más cercano a la posición actual.

Es decir, si mi posición actual es:

```
Mi posición 45.00 45.00
```

y el listado de cajeros es:

```
Cajero1 45.00 45.70
Cajero2 54.00 23.00
Cajero3 33.00 34.23
Cajero4 32.54 98.00
```

Debería geoposicionarme solo el cajero1. ¿Existe algún método en la clase MapsActivity para que busque el más cercano?

Comment: los datos de los cajeros, los tienes en un array local, sqlite o bien los cargas mediante json de un servidor?

Comment: Cojo los cajeros de un json de un servidor y los agrego a sqlite. Por lo que para coger la lista de cajeros hago una consulta a la base de datos y los guardo en un array local.

Comment: Podrías utilizar [`Location#distanceTo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29) para evaluar la distancia entre tu punto y los de los cajeros, luego escoger el más cercano en base al menor valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción seria recorrer todo la lista de cajeros y con la siguiente función [distFrom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837872/calculate-distance-in-meters-when-you-know-longitude-and-latitude-in-java)

```
public static float distFrom(float lat1, float lng1, float lat2, float lng2) {
    double earthRadius = 6371000; //3958.75 miles or 6371.0 kilometers
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
               Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
               Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    float dist = (float) (earthRadius * c);

    return dist;
    }
```

O bien si prefieres utilizar el [Location#distanceTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29) que comenta el compañero @Luiggi-Mendoza.

Calcular la distancia de cada cajero con la localización del usuario, para eso debes añadir un nuevo campo `dist` en la lista, después la ordenas de menor a mayor con ese nuevo campo.

En caso de tener muchos cajeros y no es optimo usar eso, puedes probar algo mixto [query-by-proximity-in-android (en)](http://goodenoughpractices.blogspot.com.es/2011/08/query-by-proximity-in-android.html)